# Vagrant folder sync not working correctly. Seeing the files but PHP cant detect function (does work on different enviroment)

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-plugin, vagrant-share

Just got a new Ubunut Laptop with an SSD. Trying to run my project on Vagrant which works on my desktop (with normal hdd) but I am not able to run it on this laptop. 
I am getting weird error that php function can not be found. Futher investigation pointed out that the files are not being found when trying to autoload them threw composer and psr0 or psr4 rules.

- Guest additon it the same as the VBoxManager. 5.2.34
- Vagrant 2.2.6
- Vagrant box Ubuntu 18.04
- Host OS Ubuntu 18.04
- SSD INTEL HBRPEKNX0202A
  PHTE907600JE512B-1

Answer (score 0):

After diging threw --debug outputs i found out that the VBGuest is not being treated right and failing at certain spots in the provision.

I have set a `confit.vbguest.auto_update = false` and then installed fresh box. 
Dowloaded a VBguest.iso file from VirtualBox website and installed it manually.

After `vagrant reload` everything mounted just as expected.